# PHP - искажение русского текста в сессии

Tags: php, кодировка, сессия

Определенный текст в кодировке win1251 сохраняется в сессию. И затем содержимое переменной сессии выводится. Если эта переменная уже существует, то текст просто выводится. Кодировка страницы win1251.
Т.е. как-то так:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['text']))
  $_SESSION['text'] = get_text();
echo $_SESSION['text'];
```

Проблема в том, что при незаданной переменной (т.е. прямо после присваивания) текст выдается нормально. А вот после перезагрузки страницы символы заменяются на '??????'.
Переводить текст в utf-8 пробовал. Не помогло.

Answer (score 1):

А явно на каждой странице/классе пробовали указывать?

```
header( "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" );
```